# PHP GD :image re size with some black rectangles?

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to accomplish this task for 2 days, read various stuffs online but still can't find out what is happen, also read all here at SO about similar problems but nothing.

I have image 400x400 and want to generate 120x120 using php gd. using this code:

```
                    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(120,120);
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($X_IMAGE);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 400, 400);
    // RETURN
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($image_p, null, 70);
            //destroy...
```

$X_IMAGE is 400x400 JPG that is stored as string.
All images are generated in 120x120 but most of them have some BLACK rectangle at bottom at some pictures it is larger on some it is smaller but 50% of images are with that square. So all are VISIBLE, just some part of image is covered with that black color. What would be solution for my problem? All source images are JPG and also those 120x120 that I need are JPG as you can see...

Comment: Your code looks ok. What `$X_IMAGE` contains?

Comment: What is the output if you just replace the last line with `imagejpeg($image, null, 70);`?

Comment: $X_IMAGE is 400x400 image stored as STRING in database. When I remove "imagejpeg($image, null, 70);" image is not shown. Also, that 'black rectangle' is NEVER covering image that is on image, for example if that is pair of shoes or some other product, it is always visible 100% and bellow I see black rectangle, somwhere that rectangle is 10-20 px height and sometime it is 100-120px height, but with is always full 100% of newly created image = 120px

Comment: Ok. I asked you to try to edit the last line in order to output original `$image` instead of the resampled `$image_p`. Just to see if GD renders black rectangles also on the source image (and so, we can exclude a resample problem).

Comment: Ok,I tried output of $image, and in that case images are OK, but that are still 400x400 imgs :) So any ideas?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Can you post somewhere the content of `$X_IMAGE` or an example of a 400x400 image with its wrong resampled 120x120 version?

Comment: surre, here is BIG image:http://i43.tinypic.com/9v8pz8_th.jpg and here is SMALL(problematic) image:http://i39.tinypic.com/5n4t36_th.jpg

Comment: I made small mistake, it is resizing from 240x240 to 120x120, all the time I am talking 400x400... anycas it not matter for this problem...

Comment: I also tried with 'imagecopyresized' insted of 'imagecopyresampled' but same results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your original image is not a square! You pass 400x400 to `imagecopyresampled`, but the height of the original image maybe is not 400px!

In the image you posted, for example, you have a not-squared original image. When you tell PHP to resample a square on anther image resource, you will resample the image plus a non-existent rectangle at the bottom.

The solution depends on what you want to output.

- Do you want a scaled image that keeps ratio? For example, from 400x300 to 120x90.
- Or a scaled image that not keeps ratio? For example, from 400x300 to a distorted 120x120?
- Or a cropped thumbnail? 400x300 to a 120x120 with left and right parts trimmed out a little?
- Do you want to replace the black rectangle with a white one, so fill the resampled image in that way?

Comment: "Do you want to replace the black rectangle with a white one, so fill the resampled image in that way" , EXACTLY!, how to do that ?

Comment: Try, before output, to do `imagefill($image_p, 0, 120 - 1, imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255));`. Or, just after the first line of code `imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255));`. Try both.

Comment: OK,it WORKS! BIG THANKS! I tried on 5000 sample, which in previous attempts returned about 50% images with back block, and now after adding this BEFORE output everything works just perfect! Thanks again. Now I just don't understand this: I get that this function fill space for new image with WHITE color but why coordinate is '120-1' and why '120' DON'T work and '120-1' WORKS? Anycase thanks you saved me a day, but would like to hear what is this about?

Comment: The function fill a portion of the image with a color, just as old school MS Paint does. I just filled your image with white color starting from the most left-bottom pixel. Simply, the last line of your image is 119 on Y-coordinate, because first one is 0 and not 1. Please accept my answer clicking on the tick under the big vote number.

Comment: Thanks so much on solution and explanation!